# Return maximum value of the integer at index k in array

Tags: algorithm

This question was asked during Microsoft interview for intern position, I have no idea how to even approach this.

Array has n positive integers, sum of all elements in the array is at most max_sum, absolute difference between any two consecutive elements in the array is at most 1.
Return maximum value of the integer at index k in array.

```
Input : n = 3, max_sum = 7, k = 1
Output: 3
In this case let's say array is [2,3,2]

Input: n = 4, max_sum = 6, k = 2
output = 2
In this case let's say array is [1,1,2,1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a brute-force approach. A better solution would be to *calculate* the values, but I'll leave it to you do figure that out. This is your challenge to get the job, right?

```java
Input: n = 7, max_sum = 34, k = 4
```

1. Set all values to `0`.

   ```java
   //                    ↓ k
   array = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, sum = 0
   ```
2. Since we want maximum value at `k`, with lowest sum, just increment the value to `1`.

   ```java
   //                    ↓ k
   array = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, sum = 1 (+1)
   ```
3. Since consecutive elements must be at most `1` apart, when we increment value at `k` again, we need to increment the neighboring values too.

   ```java
   //                    ↓ k
   array = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0 }, sum = 4 (+3)
   ```
4. Repeat, repeatedly.

   ```java
   //                    ↓ k
   array = { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 }, sum = 9 (+5)

   array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2 }, sum = 15 (+6)

   array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3 }, sum = 22 (+7)

   array = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4 }, sum = 29 (+7)
   ```
5. We can't repeat again, because we'd get `sum = 29 + 7 = 36` if we did, and that would exceed `max_sum = 34`.

Result: Max value at `k` is **`6`**.

There are many ways to distribute the remaining 5 points, to get the exact sum, but showing a solution with the exact sum isn't the goal, so we don't need to do anything about the 5 extra points.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define *a* as average array value:

```
a = max_sum / n
```

Let's find the maximum for k = 0:

```
max(0) = a + n/2
```

In this case, all other values of array would decrease, so the last value will be

```
a - n/2
```

for k = 1 we can see that maximum will not exceed max(0)-1, so

```
max(1) = a + n/2 - 1
```

and so on until k = n/2. for k > n/2 the max value will increase up to a + n/2 at k = n-1, so we have "V"-like curve with minimum at k=n/2, equal to a.

The only thing rest is to properly process border conditions, odd or even n and so on. I hope you got the idea.

Comment: *"There is no need in algorithm"* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) defines **algorithm** as "a finite sequence of well-defined, computer-implementable instructions". [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/algorithm) defines it as "a procedure for solving a mathematical problem (as of finding the greatest common divisor) in a finite number of steps that frequently involves repetition of an operation". Note that repetition is not required. As such, `a = max_sum / n` is an algorithm. Any math formula that is computer-implementable is an algorithm.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I meant there is no need in iterations or brute force :)

Comment: Then you should edit the answer and say that instead.